# Why are these constraints in table header view ambiguous?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a "tableHeaderView", which is a UIView. It contains a UIImageView, whose height is set to 200:

```
let tableView: UITableView = .init(frame: .zero)
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(tableView)

let tableHeaderView: UIView = .init(frame: .zero)
tableHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let imageView: UIImageView = .init(frame: .zero)
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tableHeaderView.addSubview(imageView)

tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView

var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

// Set imageView's leading and trailing to tableHeaderView's leading and trailing
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[imageView]-0-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["imageView": imageView]
)

// Set imageView's top and bottom to tableHeaderView's top and bottom
// Also, set imageView's height to 200
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[imageView(200)]-0|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["imageView": imageView]
)

// Set tableHeaderView's width to tableView's width
constraints.append(
    NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: tableHeaderView,
        attribute: .width,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: tableView,
        attribute: .width,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)

// Set tableView's leading and trailing to view's leading and trailing
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[tableView]-0-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["tableView": tableView]
)

// Set tableView's top and bottom to view's top and bottom
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[tableView]-0-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["tableView": tableView]
)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

These constraints give me this result:

[image]

You can see that several cells are covered by the header view. When I use UI debugger, this is what I get:

[image]

It tells me that tableHeaderView's constraints are ambiguous, however, no warning messages were printed in the console. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: set  imageview.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, thank you. Didn't work tho

Comment: Try the same with tableHeaderView and check are you able to see it

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, nope still didn't work. I actually don't think it'll ever work because how can my constraints be simpler? I'll give up and try another approach. Thank you anyway!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Objective c code, through this you can get idea whats gonna be wrong.

- Tableview constraint should be with self.view
- Header constraint should be with your tableview
- Add your final constraint in self.view

I just created sample class for objective c, should not matter for swift, Just compare the logic.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableview;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

NSLayoutConstraint *leftconstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                      constraintWithItem:self.tableview
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                      multiplier:1.0
                                      constant:0.0];
leftconstraint.active = YES;

NSLayoutConstraint *rightconstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:self.tableview
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem:self.view
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                       constant:0.0];
rightconstraint.active = YES;

NSLayoutConstraint *topconstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintWithItem:self.tableview
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:self.view
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                     constant:0.0];
topconstraint.active = YES;

NSLayoutConstraint *bottomconstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                        constraintWithItem:self.tableview
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.view
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                        multiplier:1.0
                                        constant:0.0];
bottomconstraint.active = YES;

[self.view addConstraints:@[leftconstraint, rightconstraint, topconstraint, bottomconstraint]];

// header view constraint

NSLayoutConstraint *left = [NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:headeerView
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                            toItem:self.tableview
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                            multiplier:1.0
                            constant:0.0];
left.active = YES;


NSLayoutConstraint *right = [NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:headeerView
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                            toItem:self.tableview
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                            multiplier:1.0
                            constant:0.0];
right.active = YES;

NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint
                             constraintWithItem:headeerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:self.tableview
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             multiplier:1.0
                             constant:0.0];
top.active = YES;

NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:headeerView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:self.tableview
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                           multiplier:1.0
                           constant:0.0];
width.active = YES;

[self.view addConstraints: @[left,right,top,width]];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];



self.tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
self.tableview.delegate=self;
self.tableview.dataSource=self;

[self.tableview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];

headeerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
[headeerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

self.tableview.tableHeaderView = headeerView;

[self.view addSubview:self.tableview];

}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableviewcell"];
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"tableviewcell"];

return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 5;
}


@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UITableView should be managing the layout of the header for you, so you'd just need to set the height of the container view (in your case tableHeaderView) and add/layout its subviews according to your needs. Why not try this and see if it works:

```
    let tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(),
                                     size: CGSize(width: 0, height: someHeightConstant)) )
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)

    tableHeaderView.addSubview(imageView)
    //now you should set constraints on the imageview (omitting the code for readability)

    tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
```

In case you need, the header to overlay the cells when the user scrolls, consider using a section header instead. Hope this helps and I correctly understood your question.